# How can i match gestures and compare them?

Tags: opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I am developing a gesture recognition project. My goal is that the webcam captures my gestures and matches them with the existing gestures in my database. I have been able to capture hand gestures and store them in my project folder. Now, how exactly do i compare them? I am clueless about this part. I have gone through so many youtube links and most of them just show them how it works and none of them explains what algorithm they have used. I am completely stuck  and all i want is some ideas or any possible link which can help me understand this matching part. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use a classification machine learning algorithm like [logistic regression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression).
This algorithm tries to minimize the cost function to predict a picture input similarity to all classes (all gestures in your case) and it'll pick the most similar class and give you that. for pictures you should use each pixel as a feature for your data.
After feeding your algorithm with enough training set it can classify your picture into one of the gestures, and as you said you are working with webcam images the running time wouldn't be that much.
Here is a great [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLx4diIP83I) for learning logistic regression by professor Andrew Ng of Stanford.

Answer (score 0):

There are many different approaches that you can follow here.

If your images are of good quality, then you could detect feature points in your input image, and then match them with a "prior/template" representation of a similar gesture. This would be a brute-force search. Here, you can use SIFT to detect keypoints and generate descriptors for each image, and then match them based on the BFMatcher or FLANN. All of the above are implemented in OpenCV. Just read the documentation.

Docs here: [detect/match](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_detection/feature_detection.html#feature-detection)

On the other hand, you could use a Bag-Of-Words approach. A good primer for that approach is here: [BoW](http://www.cs.ucf.edu/~mtappen/cap5415/lecs/lec17.pdf)

Comment: :-Since i am using color detection (basically red color) i was thinking that i can use this approach of drawing red lines on a webcam frame and then apply THE hOUGH lINE transform to count the number of lines. Then may be i can do something like this -  if the number of lines detected is say 2 then do this, if its 4 then do this etc etc. What do you think of this approach?

Comment: @Rebecca I have no idea if it will work because I have not seen the images that you are working with, and without visualizing them, I cannot provide an opinion. If you provide a link with an image that you have, then maybe I can suggest something.

Comment: :-Thanks for your reply. I want an advise from you. My colored object detection code  is dependent on the brightness,and background objects etc. What i mean to say, it works perfectly when i am at the same position where i filtered out the surrounding object. Is there any way i can make my code more independent of the background objects and lighting effects etc? I want my code to work at any position/location.Any advise on that?

Comment: What do you mean filtering out the surrounding object? Are you segmenting the image before you do gesture recognition. Again, I cannot provide a conclusive answer if I don't have an example of the images that you are working with.